# Converting all variadic arguments into a single std::string via move semantics

Tags: string, lambda, c++17, move, variadic

I have a class that contains a lambda function that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
private:
    inline static std::string text{};

public:
    template<typename...T>
    inline static auto func = [](T&&...args) mutable throw() {
        text += std::string(args...);
    };

    void show() {
        std::cout << text << '\n';
    }
};
```

My intended use would be something like this:

```
int main() {
    Foo bar;
    bar.func<std::string, int, std::string>( "Hello, I am", 39, "years old!");
    bar.show();
    return 0;
}
```

I want the templated variadic lambda to take in any type of parameter that is a basic type such as `string`, `char*`, `char[]`, `int`, `float`, `double`, etc... and to convert all of them into a single std::string that will be stored within the class.

When I run my code as such:

```
int main() {
    Foo bar;
    bar.func<string>( "Hello world!");
    bar.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything compiles fine, however, when I begin to add in various types such as the example from the intended use above, it fails to compile. Microsoft Visual Studio is giving me a `C2400` compiler error:  cannot convert from initialize list to std::string. No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous...

I believe I understand why it is ambiguous as that's not so much the issue. My question is what would be the proper and efficient way of using "move semantics or perfect forwarding"? I'm trying to avoid a bunch of copies of temporaries.

Comment: Please, can you add an example (a call) that gives a compiler error?

Comment: @max66 the intended use is the one that is generating the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use fold expressions:

```
template<typename...T>
inline static auto func = [](T&&...args) mutable throw() {
    text += (toString(args) + ...);
};
```

where toString is defined as:

```
template<class T>
std::string toString(T&& t){
    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<std::decay_t<T>>)
        return std::to_string(std::forward<T>(t));
    else
        return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

you can extend `toString` to handle all types you need to convert to `string`.
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/JBjUYy)

Comment: Hmm, fold expressions works out nicely here! The code compiles, runs and prints out the expected except a minor detail. With the example call above, the output is displayed as: "I am39years old." So now I need a way to include a space between each variadic parameter but not before the first nor after the last...